# Add an external link in React Router Dom v6?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Can't see a way in V6 to dynamically add an external link without the router prepending the site URL. Just need to do something like this:

`<a href={dynamicStrValue} target='_blank' rel='noreferrer'>Link</a>`

Comment: I don't think react-router does anything like that. What's the value of `dynamicStrValue`?

Comment: `react-router-dom` is used for internal links. If you need an external link just use a plain anchor (`<a />`) tag.

Comment: The issue is that, at least in V6, even a plain anchor tag is intercepted by react-router and the href is appended to the current route.

Comment: That just simply isn't a true statement. RRD won't touch raw anchor tags it isn't rendering. See this running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/add-an-external-link-in-react-router-dom-v6-s592sg?file=/src/App.js) example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your link must be prepended with the protocol i.e. `https://`. Otherwise, it will append to the site URL. In your case:

```js
<a href={'https://' + dynamicStrValue} target='_blank' rel='noreferrer'>Link</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
<Link to={{ pathname:`https://example.com/${dynamicStrValue}`}} target="_blank">My link</Link>
```

Referring to their [docs](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#link)

> `<Link to>` with a .. behaves differently from a normal  when
> the current URL ends with /.  ignores the trailing slash, and
> removes one URL segment for each ... But an  value handles ..
> differently when the current URL ends with / vs when it does not.

Answer (score 0):

Your link must include the protocol to avoid RR prepending the site url.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I was having the same problem as you, when executing an external component using  a plain anchor tag it was redirecting to the router, instead of opening a blank page.

The solution to my problem was simply removing the key param in the anchor tag as follows

```
<a key={item.key} href='{item.url}' target='_blank'> {item.title} <a/>
```

to

```
<a href='{item.url}' target='_blank'> {item.title} <a/>
```